# Shallow copy not working in python

Tags: python, shallow-copy

I tried to do shallow copy, but it's not working for me.

```
import copy
a = [1,2,3,4]
b = copy.copy(a)
```

Now both `a` and `b` will have same values [1,2,3,4]. But if I append `b.append(1)`, it is not reflected in a.

```
b.append(1)
print(b)
[1,2,3,4,1]
```

But in a

```
print(a)
[1,2,3,4]
```

Can anyone explain please?

Comment: *Why did you make a copy* if you *don't want separate objects*?

Comment: @Vivek I was also thinking same as you when I read that `slice` operation for lists creates a shallow copy but it wasn't behaving the way I was expecting. I was using a list of numbers. I think shallow copy and deep copy isn't different for primitive types like integers. It behaves the same way for strings as well as they are immutable. It will make more sense to experiment between shallow copy and deep copy in case of objects.

Answer (score 2):

First thing first: what you get is the expected behaviour. "shallow" copy means that you create a new copy of the object, so adding to list `b` will obviously NOT impact list `a`.

> I just want to understand difference between deepcopy and shallow copy. Because shallowcopy and deepcopy is behaving in same manner

In your example, you are doing a shallow copy of mutable container (a list) containing immutable objects (integers), so the result is indeed the same. To find out the difference between shallow and deep copies you have to use a list containing mutable objects - dicts for example:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = [{"name":"a"}, {"name":"b"}] 
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a[0]["age"] = 42
>>> a
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
>>> b
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
>>> a.append({"bar":"baaz"})
>>> a
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'bar': 'baaz'}]
>>> b
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
>>> id(a)
139833628392264
>>> id(b)
139833599561240
>>> [id(x) for x in a]
[139833628091568, 139833599520392, 139833599544128]
>>> [id(x) for x in b]
[139833628091568, 139833599520392]
```

As you can see, `a` and `b` are distinct objects - they have different ids, and adding to one doesn't add to the other - but they (initially at least) share the same objects (just after the copy `a[0]` and `a[1]` are pointing to the same objects as `b[0]` and `b[1]`).

Now if you do a deep copy:

```
>>> c = copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> c
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'bar': 'baaz'}]
>>> [id(x) for x in c]
[139833599544408, 139833599594576, 139833599596256]
>>> c[0]["age"] = 84
>>> c
[{'age': 84, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'bar': 'baaz'}]
>>> a
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}, {'bar': 'baaz'}]
>>> b
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'}]
>>>
```

you can see that `c` elements are themselves copies (distinct objects) of `a` elements.

If you really want to understand how names, objects and references work in Python, [Ned Batchelder's article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) is a great reference.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what shallow copy does. Your list elements will be the same, but the list itself will be a different object.

If you want to have another reference to the same list, do this instead:

```
b = a
```

Comment: Then what deep copy does. b =  copy.deepcopy(a)

Comment: For `[ [x] ]` -> `copy.copy` gives you a new list with the same `[x]` element. `copy.deepcopy` gives you `x` in a new list, which is itself in a new list.

Answer (score 0):

A copy makes `a` and `b` distinct list objects that store the same items:

```
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import copy
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a is b
False
```

The shallow copy does however mean that the items internal to the list *are* the same, for example:

```
>>> a = [object(), "foo", "bar"]
>>> b = copy.copy(a)
>>> a[0] is b[0]
True
>>> a[1] is b[1]
True
```

If what you want is just a reference you could just assign:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> b = a
>>> a is b
True
>>> b.append(1)
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: so copy.copy() is not used for shallow copy, as they both are having different reference.

Comment: No, No, Sorry, I just want to understand difference between deepcopy and shallow copy. Because shallowcopy and deepcopy is behaving in same manner.

Comment: @Vivek, that's not what your question asks